# Spoof a chromebook's MAC address

Tags: wireless-networking, mac-address, google-chrome-os, chromebook, spoofing

How can I temporarily change a chromebook's MAC address? I know this can be done on Windows with certain tools, and Android with root privileges, but can it be done on Chrome OS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your chromebook must be in [developer mode](http://www.howtogeek.com/210817/how-to-enable-developer-mode-on-your-chromebook/) for these commands to work.

1. Open the [Crosh Shell](http://www.chromegeek.com/what-is-crosh-shell/).
2. If your command line says `crosh` enter the command `shell`.
3. Enter `sudo ifconfig eth0 down` to shut down the internet connection.
4. Enter `sudo ifconfig eth0 hw ether 00:11:22:33:44:55` to change the MAC address to 00:11:22:33:44:55 (replace this with the new desired MAC).
5. Enter `sudo ifconfig eth0 up` to turn the internet back on.

For wireless connections, replace all instances of `eth0` with `wlan0`.

Note: Once you reboot your chromebook, the original MAC will be restored.

Comment: It is the general way to change MAC address in any UNIX-like OS. Chromium OS uses Linux kernel.

Answer (score 0):

If your chromebook or Chrome os is mananged by an Admin, you can not change your MAC address unless your the admin,or ask the admin to go into Dev mode. Because its blocked.